# Click from PDF line to source code in Texmaker doesn't work

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, forward-inverse-search

I saw that this question was raised, but did not find an answer. I'm running Texmaker 5.1.3, the "clic to jump" function doesn't work even -synctex=1 is written. My file including multiple inputs, if it's matters. setting the current document as main does not help either. Quick build - PdfLatex. Please help to make the transition between Pdf and source code work.
My options [image]

Comment: I discovered that I had this problem due to the fact that my folder was in OneDrive. Once I pulled it out of there, everything fell into place. But this works only if your file does not consist of many files. But in my case I cant find solution.